# UPDATE based on DISTINCT in same table

Tags: mysql

In my MySQL table I've 192 rows with the same value in the field `number`, the value is 548.

I need distinct update this 192 rows with new value calculate from rand function in MySQL.

Each row should have a different value calculated random.

I tried this solution but in update I've still duplicate rows with the same value ...

```
UPDATE `tbl`
SET number = FLOOR(100 +(RAND() * 150))
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT number)
AND number = 548;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update tbl set number = FLOOR(100 +(RAND() * 150)) where number = 548;
```

No need to check for number and running `DISTINCT`. If number is not present, it will simply update nothing.

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65737/1)